# Creating Reproducible Random Numbers Between 0 and 1 (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, random

I'm trying to figure out how to assign every record (row) in one of my tables a unique number (value) between 0 and 1 in SQL Server 2008. I have reviewed the rand(checksum(newid())) type methods and this appears to be appropriate with the exception that I need my set of values to be reproducible (i.e. if I run the same query multiple times I will get identical random values).

Any idea how I could go about this?

Comment: Store the mapping in a table? That would be a straightforward way to do it, and quite database-y

Comment: This may not solve my issue, maybe more specifically I need to have the sequence reproducible by any persons whom had the same original starting table. This is for a research project where the results will need to be reproducible by anyone given the same data

Comment: So you want a random generator that will produce random numbers in a repeatable (e.g. non-random) fashion? Why not just generate the set of random numbers once, then build a script consisting of a set of insert statements based on the output?

Comment: This question is going to split hairs on what "random" means.

Comment: I'm just hoping to be able to get the same set of random numbers twice. In other programs there is often a set.seed() type function which will allow me to tell the random number generator where to start and thus produce the same set of values multiple times given the same seed. I'm not a frequent SQL user (clearly...), but this is my goal

Comment: You can set the seed of rand() - so is there some feature like an ID that they each have... that would be reproducible anywhere assuming everyone uses sql server 2008. If you don't like this then maybe some kind of hashing method of some feature of the data would be good?

Answer (score 1):

Just like it was already mentioned in comments, you ether get random numbers or your get "some" numbers that appear random but can be recreated every time.

If you just need 0 or 1 you could do something like this.

```
SELECT ABS(CONVERT(BIGINT, HASHBYTES('SHA1', name)) % 2)
FROM sys.objects
```

By using Mudolo `%` function you will only get 0, 1, -1. Than you wrap it with `ABS` absolute value to get only 1 and 0.

I hope this gets you in the right direction. You can read about `HASHBYTES` here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx you can experiment with different available algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop through the rows one at a time to get a different random value for each row. To make sure it is the same random sequence each time, pick a fixed seed, and call RAND(seed) with that seed once. Each call (in the same session) to RAND() after that will give you the next number in sequence for that seed, and will always produce the same sequence for a given seed.

There are different ways to do the looping (e.g. using a cursor), but here's one to get you started.

```
create table RandomValues
(
    Id  int,
    RandomValue float
)
go

-- Pick a value and always use the same one to get reproducible random numbers
declare @FixedSeed int
set @FixedSeed = 100

declare @Id int
declare @MaxId int

select @MaxId = MAX(Id), @Id = MIN(Id) from OriginalData

-- You don't need this value for anything, you just need a call to rand(@FixedSeed) 
-- to start the sequence with the fixed seed
declare @dummyseed float
set @dummyseed = rand(@FixedSeed)

while (@Id <= @MaxId)
  begin
    insert RandomValues
    select Id, rand()
    from   OriginalData
    where   Id = @Id

    -- Get the next Id from the original table
    select  @Id = MIN(Id)
    from    OriginalData
    where   Id > @Id
end

select od.*, rv.RandomValue 
from RandomValues rv
join OriginalData od on rv.Id = od.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

As a number of people have already suggested, how about a lookup table for random numbers. If the main table has an integer key the following code could be used to generate a suitable lookup table;

```
;with t as (
   select 1 as i 
   union all 
   select i + 1 
   from t 
   where i < 1000) -- adjust accordingly
select 
   i, 
   cast(abs(checksum(newid())) / 2147483647.0 as float) as r -- the RAND function returns a float.
into dbo.RandomNumbers
from 
   t 
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

If you don't want to go down the lookup route then you need a function that will return a repeatable random number. I've tried a few different things and come up with `rand(checksum(i,1.0/i))`. It still needs an integer key.

```
;with t as (
   select 1 as i 
   union all 
   select i+1 
   from t 
   where i<1000) -- adjust accordingly
select 
   i, 
   rand(checksum(i,1.0/i)) as r
from 
   t 
option(maxrecursion 0)
```

Please note that neither of the above ideas addresses the unique aspect of your question, and I haven't analysed the distribution of the numbers but how important these are depends on what your doing.

Rhys